# Help on proving an observation related to pythagorean triangles.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Working for a while on Pythagorean triangles I observed that if

$n$ has the prime factorization $p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r^2}...p_i^{r_i}$ where $r_k$'s not all even Then we have:

$\frac{(r_1+1)(r_2+1)...(r_i+1)}{2}$ number of pythagorean triangles with side $n$.

As an example if $n=5=1\cdot 5$ we only have $2$. Namely (3,4,5) and (5,12,13).

My question is, is it true in general? And if it is true, can someone prove it for me? Lastly what will be the formula if all $r_k$'s are even?

Comment: In case $n=5$ you have $i=1$ and $r_1=1,$ so that $(r_1+1)/2=1.$ So here your formula predicts one triangle, yet as you note there are two. [Is there a simple adjustment of your formula to correspond with several known cases?]

Comment: @coffeemath we have $p_1=1$ and $p_2=5$

Comment: @coffeemath the proof is trivial if $n$ is prime.

Comment: Jr Antalan: Usually 1 is not considered to be a prime number. If you do and always use $1^1$ for that contribution, it's the same as if you omit using $1$ as a prime and double your formula, which then means it doesn't need the division by $2$. Another thing to note is that if $n$ is a prime of the form $4n+3$ then it will not be the hypotenuse of a Pythagorean triple, so there is a difference in the count depending on $n$ mod 4 when $n$ is a prime.

Comment: Got your point @coffeemath thanks.

Comment: Yes, for example I think $n=7$ only appears in the triple $(7,24,25).$ It's easy to get any prime as the $p^2-q^2$ part of the triple $(p^2-q^2,2pq,p^2+q^2,$ by using adjacent $p,q.$ By the way, nice question!

Comment: I take $n=54=2^13^3$. There are only $3$ Pythagorean triangles (where $a<b<c$, $a^2+b^2=c^2$): $$(54,72,90), (54,240,246), (54,728, 730).$$

Comment: @coffeemath thanks, to Oleg567 thanks, thus my observation is not true in general.

Comment: @JrAntalan, perhaps your observation will still work with **added restrictions** on $n$ (e.g., divisibility constraints)?